# Maven : pom.lastUpdated exists but no jar

Tags: maven

I would like some clarification on something. I have some dependencies in my ~/.m2/repository that do not contain a jar.

I checked out a project from one of my colleauges recently and noticed that the build failed because it could find maven-settings 2.7 in my repository or in artifactory.

When I opened my repository I saw that the folder structure for the dependency existed ie ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-settings/2.0.7 but inside the folder there was no jar and only a maven-settings-2.0.7.pom and a maven-settings-2.0.7.pom.lastupdated.

Is this a result of invoking mvn clean install with the -U (update snapshots) flag. And if so, is there an easy way to remove all these dependencies that dont actually contain a jar?

Comment: The option `-U`  is related to SNAPSHOT but not to releases. This is more related that you are not able to download the appropriate dependencies like the above maven-settings-2.0.7...This shows me that you don't use a repository manager in your company...

Comment: Hmm.. seems like I will have to remove all the xx.jar.lastUpdated files...what a pain.